# Does the base have any information about the classes derived from them?

Tags: c++

this question was asked on a site I thought it must be having an information about it as when we create an abstract class it is the condition that pure virtual function must be implemented in the derived class.

Comment: Are you using CRTP or regular inheritance?

Comment: The parent class doesn't need to know anything about the child class, it's enough that the *compiler* knows all of that.

Answer (score 1):

The base class doesn't have any info about their subclasses.
Its subclasses have info about base class.

Comment: Depends what you mean on info.  with [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) the base class can access all public members of the derived class.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I mean in Regular. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't know about CRTP. Very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Generally it depends what you name "Information"
If you have declared virtual functions inside a base class
You can say the compile generates a Jump list inside the base class and when you derive from that base class and declare a function that has the same declaration as the virtual base class function the compiler just place the address of the function from the derived class to that jumplist in base class.
And this of course is done by the derived class.

if you have an inheritance chain the last instantiated class will place the address of its function. And when the base class tries to call the function it just uses the jump list to jump to right function.